# Method to serve static website alongside SPA on one URL

Tags: ftp, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm building a Vue SPA web application with a Django API backend, served using Google Kubernetes Engine. The company I'm working for has a designer who has built the landing page and contact page in webflow. The designer requires the ability to update the landing page and contact page on the live website whenever she changes something, and I'd rather not have to rebuild the entire app whenever this happens (as well as install the necessary software on her system, like Docker).

Is there a solution available to serve the Vue SPA part of the website through Google Kubernetes Engine, while serving the static pages through a different method, that she can simply update through SFTP?

Comment: Consider uploading the static parts to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) which then you can use `gcloud rsync` to update static files. You can deploy an nginx container or a Python app to GKE that proxies the static requests to GCS fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Consider uploading the static parts to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) which then you can use gcloud rsync to update static files. You can deploy an nginx container or a Python app to GKE that proxies the static requests to GCS fairly easily